# Spring security SecurityConfig class - problem with authentication form login

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

I've been trying to use formLogin in my securityFilterChain method and for some reason it doesn't want to go in defaultSuccessUrl.

Here is my code:

SecurityConfig.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            var user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);
            if (user == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
            }
            return user;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        var authManagerBuilder = http.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
        authManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService())
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());

        http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

        http.exceptionHandling(eh -> eh.accessDeniedPage("/forbidden"));

        http.formLogin(fl -> fl.loginProcessingUrl("/auth") // <form action "/auth"
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .failureUrl("/login?error"));

        http.logout(lg -> lg.logoutUrl("/logout")
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/login"));

        return http.build();
    }

}
```

HomeController.class

```
@Controller
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class HomeController {

    private final UserService userService;

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String homePage() {
        return "home";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")
    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/forbidden")
    public String forbiddenPage() {
        return "forbidden";
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAnonymous()")
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String createUser(User user, @RequestParam String rePassword) {
        String result = userService.registerUser(user, rePassword);
        return "redirect:/login?" + result;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("isAuthenticated()")
    @PostMapping("/change-password")
    public String changePassword(String currentPassword, String newPassword, String reNewPassword) {
        String result = userService.changePassword(currentPassword, newPassword, reNewPassword);
        return "redirect:/?" + result;
    }

}
```

login.html

```
<form action="/auth" method="post">
    <div th:if="${param.success != null}" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show text-center" role="alert">
      <strong>аккаунт успешно создан</strong>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.errorEmail != null}" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show text-center" role="alert">
      <strong>почта занята</strong>
    </div>
    <div th:if="${param.errorPassword != null}" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show text-center" role="alert">
      <strong>пароли не совпадают</strong>
    </div>
    <h2>Войти</h2>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Логин</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" name="username" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Пароль</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Войти</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#registerModal">Регистрация</button>
  </form>
```

I tried debugging it but ended up being lost in an infinite cycle in SecurityConfig, it doesn't throw any exception and sql logs are seem to be fine. Objects in DB are stored properly.

Comment: I don't see any authorization rules, so by default all URLs are denied. Why do you think it should work? Did you read Spring Security Reference to learn the basics?